# Dates and Arithmetic

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, arithmetic-expressions

I'm learning python by myself for almost a month and i was confronted with an exercise that involves "datetime" and arithmetic operators.

First - they asked me to create a code where the users should enter the deadline for their project and the code must tell them how many days they have to complete.

And i did this:

```
    import datetime  
    today = datetime.date.today()  
    delivery_date = input("Tell me your deadline (dd/mm/aa): ")

    print("\n")

    deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(delivery_date, "%d/%m/%y").date()  
    days = delivery_date - today  
    print("You have", days.days, "days to finish your project.")
```

But the second part it's kinda tricky.

Second - they are asking me to try to give the answer as a combination of weeks and days and that i will need some math functions to solve this final part.

And i did this:

```
    weeks = days // 7
    remainder_days = days % 7
    print("You have", weeks.days, "weeks and", remainder_days.days, "days.")
```

Only this final part fails. In the end i get this error message:

```
        remainder_days = days % 7
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

I know that the problem is with the modulus symbol (%) but if they are asking me to give the final result as a combination of weeks and days, it's possible, but i can't see how.

Is any other way with a simple math operation to solve this?
Do i need to put anything in my code?
Can someone help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`days = delivery_date - today` should be `days = deadline - today`. Also you should call it `delta`, because it's a time delta, where you can do `delta.days` to get the number of days. Simply use `delta.days` later on.

Also `delta.days` is just a number, so when doing `delta.days // 7`, you don't want to call `.days` on the result.

Something like the following should work:

```
import datetime  
today = datetime.date.today()  
delivery_date = input("Tell me your deadline (dd/mm/aa): ")

print("\n")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(delivery_date, "%d/%m/%y").date()  
delta = deadline - today  
print("You have", delta.days, "days to finish your project.")

weeks = delta.days // 7
remainder_days = delta.days % 7
print("You have", weeks, "weeks and", remainder_days, "days.")
```

By the way the error points you in the right direction: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'`. It means you have a time delta object, on which you're applying the modulo operator with an integer, and python tells you it's not possible. So you'll need to somehow get an integer out of your time delta.

Comment: OMG it works, thank you very much @user276648. 

Im just new to programming so i need to learn more about datetime even knowing is a pain in the @#s. Thank you very much man!

I just have a question about your answer. You say i should call "delta" to the variable because its a time delta. Is that really necessary or is just a normal procedure?
 I don't know too much about it so i will check python website to learn more about it. But, really, thank you man ;)

Comment: @MárcioCunha I advise you to call it `delta`, or `time_delta`, so that when you read the code, it's more obvious what the type of the variable is. If you call it `days` you may think it's a number of days. Similarly I would rename `delivery_date` to `deadline_string`: you use only one term `deadline`, and you easily know the difference between `deadline` and `deadline_string` and which one to use. Of course it would also work with variables named just `a` and `b`, but it would be more confusing!

Comment: Ok @user276648, i will follow your advice. And again, thank you for the help man! Hope that one day to be me helping other guy too  =D